# Extracting logic from the akka-http routing class and create a method for each REST path

Tags: scala, akka-http

I wanted to be able to do something like this with akka-http:

```
// etc ... ~
path("abc" / "def") { m } // here I just define the path routing logic

// now here I take care of everything else.

// this works:
def m(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = {
  request.complete("")
}
```

but then the problems start:

```
// but this will not!:
def m(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
  request.complete("")
}

// nor this!:
def m(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
  parameters('a) { a => complete("") }
}

// nor this!:
def m(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
  parameters('a) { a => complete("") }
}

// nor this!:
def m(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
  parameters('a) { a => request.complete("") }
}
```

Any easy way to get around this issue? It's not like I'm really interested in any of the `Future` capabilities of Scala/akka-http. I'm perfectly fine with a synchronous solution at this level.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. Just apply `request`:

```
def m(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
  request.complete("")
}(request)
```